# Calculating normalized variance in monte carlo implementation of coagulation events with python

Tags: python, statistics, simulation, montecarlo

I am trying to replicate the results of the following paper (https://pennstate.pure.elsevier.com/en/publications/constant-number-monte-carlo-simulation-of-population-balances) for working with MONTE Carlo techniques in python.

I have a problem understanding what the variance calculation should be, or if I am completely mistaken on the equations I am using.

As it is, the problem is to calculate the mean mass of a system following coagulation events( two particles merge in a new particle with a total mass the sum of the merged particles), with the acceptance rule defined in a monte carlo fashion( generation of a random number and acceptance of coagulation only if the random number is smaller than a probability defined somehow).

Then I have to calculate the normalized variance, and plot is as a function of time, which means to calculate it several times during the simulation . My function looks like this:

```py
def montecarlorun(N,totalruns,model):

    particles={}
    M_k_hat=[] #number average mass or sample mean
    M_k_bar=[] #mean size
    time=[]
    distributionM=[]

    #Particle initialization of mass
    for i in range(N):
        particles[i]=mass

    #Matrices initialization

    M_k_hat.append(mass) #initial mean mass of the system
    M_k_bar.append(mass)
    time.append(0)


    #Monte Carlo runs

    #variable definitions
    c=0
    k=0
    sigma=[]
    sigmatimes=[]
    pairs=[]
    part=[]
    mean=[]
    meansq=[]
    muolist=[]
    mu2list=[]
    particlesmeanmass=0
    particlesmeanmasssq=0
    kmax=1

    #simulation
    while c<totalruns:
        prtcl1=random.randrange(N)
        prtcl2=random.randrange(N)
        r=random.uniform(0,1) #random number for acceptance probability condition
        if model==1:
            p=1
        else: # definition of probability for a second model, irrelevant to the post as it is
            p,kmax=brownian_kernel(particles[prtcl1], particles[prtcl2],kmax)
        if(r<p):
            newmass=particles[prtcl1]+particles[prtcl2] #newmass after coagulation
            prtcl_copy=random.randrange(N) #copy a particle from the list
            particles.update({prtcl1:newmass}) #update particle 1 with the new mass after the event of coagulation
            copymass=particles[prtcl_copy] #take mass of copied
            particles.update({prtcl2:copymass}) #replace particle 2 with the copy
            time.append((2/(kmax*N))*(N/(N-1))**k) #get time for event
            k=k+1 # event counter
            M_k_hat.append(M_k_hat[k-1]+(copymass/N)) # new mass of system
            M_k_bar.append((N/(N-1))**k) #same
        print(len(M_k_hat))
        print("c=",c)
        #Sigma part new:
        if(c%2000)==0:
            meanmassnow=M_k_hat[-1]
            sigmatimes.append(time[-1])
            for i in range(len(particles)):
                particlesmeanmass=particlesmeanmass+particles[i]/meanmassnow
                particlesmeanmasssq=particlesmeanmasssq+((particles[i]/meanmassnow)**2)
            muo=particlesmeanmass/N
            mu2=particlesmeanmasssq/N
            muolist.append(muo)
            mu2list.append(mu2)
        #Histograms for distributions of masses:
        if(c%2000==0):
            meanmassnow=M_k_hat[-1]
            masses=particles.values()
            masses=[x/meanmassnow for x in masses]
            d=np.histogram(masses,10,density=True)
            d=(d[0] ,0.5*(d[1][1:]+d[1][:-1]))
            distributionM.append([d,time[-1]])

        c=c+1


    for i in range(len(muolist)):
        sigma.append( (mu2list[i]/muolist[i]) - 1 )


    return particles,M_k_bar,M_k_hat,time,sigma,sigmatimes,pairs,distributionM
```

From my understanding of the paper, I tried to calculate the normalized variance from the moments of the distribution.

From the paper, there is also an analytical relation. In the paper, the analytical and simulated result are almost identical. Instead, I get:

[image: Normalized variance as function of time]

where red is the *theoretical * line and blue my simulation's result. A better understanding of the behavior of the blue curve is below:

[image]

So, the question is whether there is an algorithmic problem or whether there is a mistake on the quantity I am plotting( and I should be plotting something else). Note that, as I see it, from the moment of the distributions, the first moment would always be one.

Comment: A note: I will be posting the question also in stat stack exchange, since I am not sure if the problem is algorithmic of statistical in nature. Thanks.

Comment: Link : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/443000/calculating-normalized-variance-in-monte-carlo-implementation-of-coagulation-eve

Comment: Is there a reason for not using numpy? Python lists are not the most suitable for numeric computations like Monte Carlo simulations in terms of efficiency.

Comment: @PéterLeéh Agree. But could that be a source of the inconsistency between the plots? Thanks.